# Deploying my local app with database to Heroku

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, heroku

I am new to Rails, very new to Heroku.

I have just uploaded my application to Heroku.

But when I opened the site, I only see this error message; "We're sorry, but something went wrong."

So I the `heroku logs` command and here is the log.
It has something to do with the css file but I couldnt understand it...

```
2013-06-25T19:19:17.196893+00:00 app[web.1]: [2013-06-25 19:19:17] INFO  ruby 2.0.0 (2013-05-14) [x86_64-linux]
2013-06-25T19:19:17.196893+00:00 app[web.1]: [2013-06-25 19:19:17] INFO  WEBrick 1.3.1
2013-06-25T19:19:17.197592+00:00 app[web.1]: [2013-06-25 19:19:17] INFO  WEBrick::HTTPServer#start: pid=2 port=45226
2013-06-25T19:19:17.771088+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from starting to up
2013-06-25T19:20:03.828188+00:00 app[web.1]: => Rails 3.2.13 application starting in production on http://0.0.0.0:45226
2013-06-25T19:20:03.828188+00:00 app[web.1]: => Ctrl-C to shutdown server
2013-06-25T19:20:03.828188+00:00 app[web.1]: => Booting WEBrick
2013-06-25T19:20:03.828188+00:00 app[web.1]: => Call with -d to detach
2013-06-25T19:20:03.828188+00:00 app[web.1]: Started GET "/" for 68.45.84.42 at 2013-06-25 19:20:03 +0000
2013-06-25T19:20:08.600921+00:00 app[web.1]: 
2013-06-25T19:20:08.600921+00:00 app[web.1]: ActionView::Template::Error (Invalid CSS after "...abel { font-s  ": expected "{", was "}"
2013-06-25T19:20:08.600921+00:00 app[web.1]:     9:   <meta name="description" content="fatihnetwork.com | fatih universitesi ogrencileri bulusma platformu" />
2013-06-25T19:20:08.600921+00:00 app[web.1]:     15: </head>
2013-06-25T19:20:08.600921+00:00 app[web.1]:   (in /app/app/assets/stylesheets/application.css)):
2013-06-25T19:20:08.601453+00:00 app[web.1]: Compiled omniauth_callbacks.css  (2ms)  (pid 2)
2013-06-25T19:20:08.600921+00:00 app[web.1]:     10:   <meta name="keywords" content="fatih universitesi, fatih, fatih ¸niversitesi ¸niversite, foursquare t¸rkiye, foursquare, four square, facebook, facebook t¸rkiye" />
2013-06-25T19:20:08.600921+00:00 app[web.1]:     13:   <%= javascript_include_tag "application" %>
2013-06-25T19:20:08.601131+00:00 app[web.1]: 
2013-06-25T19:20:08.601453+00:00 app[web.1]: Processing by HomeController#index as HTML
2013-06-25T19:20:08.601453+00:00 app[web.1]:   Rendered home/index.html.erb within layouts/application (4.9ms)
2013-06-25T19:20:08.601453+00:00 app[web.1]: Compiled home.css  (119ms)  (pid 2)
2013-06-25T19:20:08.600921+00:00 app[web.1]:     12:   <%= stylesheet_link_tag    "application", :media => "all" %>
2013-06-25T19:20:08.601131+00:00 app[web.1]:   app/views/layouts/application.html.erb:12:in `_app_views_layouts_application_html_erb__4210444077502940588_70087393743220'
2013-06-25T19:20:08.601453+00:00 app[web.1]: Compiled application.css  (4111ms)  (pid 2)
2013-06-25T19:20:08.600921+00:00 app[web.1]:     11:   <meta name="Copyright" content="" />
2013-06-25T19:20:08.600921+00:00 app[web.1]:     14:   <%= csrf_meta_tags %>
2013-06-25T19:20:08.601131+00:00 app[web.1]: 
2013-06-25T19:20:08.601453+00:00 app[web.1]: Completed 500 Internal Server Error in 4241ms
2013-06-25T19:20:08.601453+00:00 app[web.1]: Compiled active_admin.css  (3753ms)  (pid 2)
```

Comment: Did you successfully test this locally before pushing it to Heroku?

Comment: yes, it works fine on the local server.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're right, it seems to be a CSS syntax error.

```
ActionView::Template::Error (Invalid CSS after "...abel { font-s  ": expected "{", was "}"
```

Means that the CSS compiler was expecting an opening bracket "{" but instead got a closing bracket "}" and doesn't know what that means. Try doing a ctrl+f or command+f to find "...abel { font-s  " in your code and see if there is a syntax error there.

Hope this helps! :)

Comment: I thought so too but I couldn't find an error anywhere in the application.css.

Comment: Just to be clear, do I run the `git push heroku master` command everytime I update the application?

Comment: Just a push won't do it. You need to add the changes to the index, then commit those changes and then finally push them.

Comment: ^^ meaning `git add /app/assets/stylesheets` followed by `git commit -m "some message"` then you can `git push heroku master` and/or push to github